# Disable syntax checking in Visual Studio 2015 (Community)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015 Community to do ASP.NET in C#.

While it might seem counterproductive, I disabled Intellisense to improve my memorization abilities for class names and members (Intellisense was too helpful and I could always type Ctrl-J if need be). I tried to do the same for C# so as to code with as few interruptions as possible in the long run, by learning from my inattention mistakes and focusing more on what I'm writing. But I can't find anything in the settings to do the job cleanly (i.e without changing the error underline color)

So is it possible to disable code syntax checking ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/disable-squiggly-or-wavy-lines-in.html
this will help you

Comment: This option seems to have been removed from Visual Studio 2015. I don't have anything like that.

Comment: Yea i am using Enterprise and its in the text editor setting, sorry

Comment: If you are using resharper i know you can tell it to show as a hint and change the squiggly line...

Comment: I'm using VS2015 community.